# MySql: Building this query without the subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transaction log table in the form:

```
| id | date       | type | symbol | volume | unit_price | user_id |
| 1  | 2016-01-01 | BUY  | AAPL   | 100    | 100.00     | a       |
| 2  | 2016-01-02 | SELL | AAPL   | 50     | 110        | a       |
```

I am trying to build a view that shows the current balance based on these transactions. Something in the form:

```
| user_id | symbol | total_volume | value |
```

So far I have:

```
SELECT 
    t.user_id,
    t.symbol,
    sum(t.volume * t.multiplier) as total_volume,
    sum(t.volume * t.unit_price * t.multiplier) as value
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE type
            WHEN 'SELL' THEN -1
            WHEN 'BUY' THEN 1
        END as multiplier
    FROM transaction
) t
GROUP BY t.user_id, t.symbol;
```

This gets me what I need but I can't create this as a view because of the sub select. Is there an alternate way I could do this which would enable me to create it as a view?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to make this query into a view?

Comment: @Mureinik Just a generic "Error whilst creating the view" but I know MySql doesnt allow sub queries in views so it's most likely that

Comment: Just replace the inline view query with a reference to the transaction table. 
And then replace the references to `t.multiplier` with the CASE expression. Whether that's required or not, it should give better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the condition in the `sum`:

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.symbol,
       sum(case when t.type = 'SELL' then - volume
                when t.type = 'BUY' then volume
            end)
          ) as total_volume,
       sum(t.volume * t.unit_price *
           (case when t.type = 'SELL' then -1
                 when t.type = 'BUY' then 1
            end))  as value
FROM transaction t
GROUP BY t.user_id, t.symbol;
```

If `type` only takes on the two values, you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.symbol,
       sum(case when t.type = 'SELL' then -t.volume else t.volume end)  as total_volume,
       sum(t.volume * t.unit_price *
           (case when t.type = 'SELL' then -1 else 1 end)
            end))  as value
FROM transaction t
GROUP BY t.user_id, t.symbol;
```

Comment: I'd prefer that the unqualified references to \`type\` be qualified, like all of the other column references. **+10**.  The "search" form of  case ... **`CASE t.type WHEN 'SELL' THEN -1 WHEN 'BUY' THEN 1 END`**  could be used.  Lots of ways to skin a cat. Just some ways  are a lot messier than others.

Comment: Is there an easy way I could also add a 'Where total_volume != 0' clause?

Comment: @Ed0906 . .. That would be `having total_volume <> 0` after the `group by`.